# Problema para conectar aplicación Visual Studio 2013 con base de datos SQL creada en cPanel MySQL

Tags: mysql, c#, sql, visual-studio-2013

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación "Windows Form Application" (en C#) empleando "visual studio 2013 community" para la empresa en la que trabajo, pretendo conectar la aplicación a una base de datos SQL que creé en el "Asistente de bases de datos MySQL®" de cPane, también creé una cuenta y le di permisos para conectarse a la base de datos. Cuando intento conectar me sale el error:

*A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing
a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not
accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server
is configured to allow remote connections. (provicler: Named Pipes
Provider, error: 40- Could not open a connection to SQL Server)*

como se puede ver en la imagen:
[image: captura del error]

He intentado de todo para solucionar el error, entre otras cosas probé poner en la parte de "Server name" tanto el "Nombre del servidor" (agregando y sin agregar ".neubox.net"), la "Dirección IP compartida" entre otras cosas, además ya agregue mi dirección IP en la sección "MySQL remoto®" (como se muestra en el primer minuto de este vídeo https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XdreQnH1krY). Nada ha funcionado hasta ahora.

Doy gracias de antemano a todos los que respondan.

Comment: La base de datos está local o en un servidor en otra pc?

Comment: El error dice que no puede conectar con una base de datos de Microsoft SQL Server y sin embargo el texto dice que se creo con el Asistente de MySQL Son dos servidores de bases de datos diferentes. Y cada uno requiere su diferente proveedor de conexión.

Comment: Japv: La base de datos está en el servidor del proveedor de la página web de la empresa en donde trabajo.

Jave fer2: ¿como lo conecto entonces? se ¿necesita descargar un complemento o algo parecido?

Comment: Estás intentando conectarte a un SQL Server, pero la base de datos la has creado con mySQL, y no son lo mismo.

Comment: Por otro lado, olvidando entornos de desarrollo y todo el ruido, hay que ir a lo básico primero. ¿Te puedes conectar al puerto del servidor usando `telnet`?. Si, el clásico `telnet miservidor.com 3306` (suponiendo que usa el puerto por defecto). Si logras conectarte desde telnet, debieras poder desde el IDE o desde tu aplicación, pero si no, entonces ni para qué batallar con estos entornos, primero configura bien el servidor para que te permita el acceso y luego platicamos.

Answer (score 0):

Primero intenta instalando [MySQL for Visual Studio](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/visualstudio/) y el [MySQL Connector/NET](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/), para que al momento de crear la conexión, en el campo *Data Source*, usando el botón *Change* puedas elegir la conexión para servidores de MySQL. Pienso que ya teniendo los parámetros de la conexión e instalando lo que te comento, no deberías tener ningún problema

Comment: Si, ya resolví el problema precisamente  instalando MySQL for Visual Studio y el MySQL Connector/NET. Gracias

Comment: Me da gusto que lo hayas podido resolver. Si mi respuesta es correcta, por favor dale un voto.